# implementing OnClickListener for a fragment on android

Tags: java, android, android-layout

I have a sliding menu project and inside home layout another layout is called as a fragment :

this is the HomeFragment.java :

```
package info.androidhive.slidingmenu;

import android.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

public class HomeFragment extends Fragment {

    public HomeFragment(){}

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);

        return rootView;
    }
}
```

I need to import this click listener inside my java class in order to submit a form .

```
//CheckFal:
            btnCheckFalAction = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnCheckFal);
            btnCheckFalAction.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {           

                  @Override
                  public void onClick(View v) 
                  {
                      Toast.makeText(this, "Hello World", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                  }    
                }
```

But when I add the above code snippet it throws me an error on  undefined methods such as findViewById , OnClickListener , onClick

The button is inside this layout fragment_home.xml

```
  <Button
      android:id="@+id/btnCheckFal"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_below="@+id/relativeLayout1"
      android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
      android:layout_marginTop="19dp"
      android:text="@string/CheckFal" />
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

While working with `Fragment`, you have to inflate view.

So when you want to use any widget you have to use view object with `findViewById()`.

Simply Do like this...

```
public class HomeFragment extends Fragment {

    public HomeFragment(){}

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);

            btnCheckFalAction = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.btnCheckFal); // you have to use rootview object..
            btnCheckFalAction.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {           

                  @Override
                  public void onClick(View v) 
                  {
                      Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Hello World", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                  }    
                });

        return rootView;
    }
}
```

OR try other way..

```
public class HomeFragment extends Fragment implements OnClickListener{

    public HomeFragment(){}

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);

            btnCheckFalAction = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.btnCheckFal); // you have to use rootview object..
            btnCheckFalAction.setOnClickListener(this);

        return rootView;
    }
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
     // TODO Auto-generated method stub
     switch(v.getId()){

     case R.id.btnCheckFal :
         //your code...
     break;

    default:
        break;

     }

    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks but OnClickListener class is undefined in this files and it says create class

Comment: make sure that you have imported correct class file that is `import android.view.View.OnClickListener;`

Comment: That's it , and what about this one : "The method makeText(Context, CharSequence, int) in the type Toast is not applicable for the arguments (new View.OnClickListener(){}, String, int)"

Comment: I am not clear with that method : I used it like this :                        Toast.makeText(this.getBaseContext(), "Hello World", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
 and still error

Comment: instead of this.getBaseContext() try using simply getActivity() i.e. Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Hello World", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

Comment: Ok another problem , if I need to call a custom object like          PersianCalendar pCal = persianDatePicker.getDisplayPersianDate();
 and I have imported all packages . but it throws me error like persianDatePicker cannot be resolved

Comment: in the second method, do not forget to change button xml file to set `onClick="onClick"`

Comment: @HojatModaresi no need for that when you are setting listener for button. If u don't want to set listener at that time you can set method like this. :)

Answer (score 3):

You can use

```
rootView.findViewById(...)
```

in your code, because your class doesn't inherit/implement this method

Comment: Thanks , but what about the other methods like OnClickListener and onClick , it still throws me error of being undefined

Comment: for that use [`new android.View.OnClickListener() {`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnClickListener.html) - checkout API docs

Comment: " android.View cannot be resolved to a type " this is the error after using it

Comment: `android.view.View`  sorry there was a typo

Answer (score 2):

first...you should findView in rootView such as

```
btnCheckFalAction = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.btnCheckFal);
```

then you can finish Button's operation

Answer (score 0):

```
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment in on create

         RelativeLayout mLinearLayout = (RelativeLayout) inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_a,
                container, false);
         cd = new ConnectionDetector(getActivity());




ImageButton mButton = (ImageButton) mLinearLayout.findViewById(R.id.imageButton1);
mButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // here you set what you want to do when user clicks your button,
        // e.g. launch a new activity

        Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"Opening Maps",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


    }
});
```

you can call this by view