# How to add onClickListener to the fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

I am wondering how to add use `setOnClickListener` for a button which I created in a fragment. Normally, I could use
 `Button buttonLoad = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonLoadPicture);` if I created the button in xml layout and was able to set an ID. I tried to solve the problems myself and found some links regarding to [FragmentTransaction](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentTransaction.html#add%28int,%20android.app.Fragment,%20java.lang.String%29) and [findFragmentByTag](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentManager.html#findFragmentByTag(java.lang.String)). I tried to implement them into my code but still couldn't find a correct way to do it. Can someone please show me a correct way to do this. Here is the code block I've got:
MainActivity.java << This is where the fragments are initialised

```
private void setupViewPager(ViewPager viewPager) {
    ViewPagerAdapter adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
    adapter.addFragment(new CameraActivity(), "Camera");
    adapter.addFragment(new GalleryActivity(), "Gallery");
    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

Basically I want to load up the media storage when the user click on Gallery.

Thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27728439/implementing-onclicklistener-for-a-fragment-on-android

Comment: The answer linked above is correct, but if you want to set the onClickListener after onCreateView has been called, you can use getView() to return the root view, and then call all the methods on this view, i.e. getView().findViewById(...)